# SQL compare and select rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with this data :

[image]

I would like to get the thread_id shared only by the user_id 140 and 1.

So in my example the result would be 356 and 358.

With this request

```
select a.user_id , b.user_id, a.thread_id 
from `wp_bp_messages_recipients` as a, `wp_bp_messages_recipients` as b 
where a.thread_id = b.thread_id 
and a.user_id = 1 
and b.user_id = 140
```

I have 356, 358, 359, but i don't want the thread_id 359 because it is shared with the user_id 5.

Thank's a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with distinct `COUNT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT thread_id
FROM table_name
WHERE thread_id NOT IN (SELECT thread_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id NOT IN (1, 140))
GROUP BY thread_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm getting the same result with this request : http://imgur.com/a/CB9wI
(testing on phpmyadmin)

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working :)
It's the fastest request possible ? I have a huge table.

Comment: I have removed one condition, try now? Yes, it should be fine as long as `thread_id` column is indexed.

Comment: it's still working, and a bit faster, still if you have an idea with one select i will take if, thank you for your time !

Comment: Can't think of any atm, however, will update the answer if I find out anything else.